# Do all degree $n+1$ polynomials have rational roots?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, roots

Do all degree $n+1$ polynomials have rational roots? It's hard to believe especially there are no clean algebraic solutions to polynomials with degrees $n\geq4$. How would you go about proving these polynomials have irrational roots?

Comment: If a polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, all roots are irrational. There are plenty of them.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^5+2$. How could it have a rational root? More generally, take $x^n+2$ for $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Moreover, the question does not rule out polynomials with irrational coefficients. And what does "degree $n+1$" mean ? degree greater than $1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_1,...,a_{n+1} \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ and consider

$p(x)=(x-a_1) \cdot ... \cdot (x-a_{n+1})$.

Then $p$ has degree $n+1$ but no rational root.